# Migration from ASP.NET Core's container to Autofac

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, autofac

I'm using ASP.NET Core and its builtin container. I want to migrate my registrations to Autofac.

The [Autifac docs](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html) don't have a "migration guide", so I want to be sure I'm doing things correctly.

```
ASP.NET Core container             -> Autofac
----------------------                -------

// the 3 big ones
services.AddSingleton<IFoo, Foo>() -> builder.RegisterType<Foo>().As<IFoo>().SingleInstance()
services.AddScoped<IFoo, Foo>()    -> builder.RegisterType<Foo>().As<IFoo>().InstancePerLifetimeScope()
services.AddTransient<IFoo, Foo>() -> builder.RegisterType<Foo>().As<IFoo>().InstancePerDependency()

// default
services.AddTransient<IFoo, Foo>() -> builder.RegisterType<Foo>().As<IFoo>()

// multiple
services.AddX<IFoo1, Foo>();
services.AddX<IFoo2, Foo>();       -> builder.RegisterType<Foo>().As<IFoo1>().As<IFoo2>().X()

// without interface
services.AddX<Foo>()               -> builder.RegisterType<Foo>().AsSelf().X()
```

There are more variations (e.g. delegates, `IEnumerable<>`), but these are the main ones.

Is this correct? Am I missing some nuance somewhere, because Autofac is quite complex.

---

**UPDATE**
Comments so far are of the "but why" variety, but that doesn't matter (though I've explained our reasoning in some of those comments). This is a legitimate question. **If you have experience with both containers, I'd really appreciate your input.**

(As a short summary of those explanations - in our many years of experience, we've learned the hard way that providing two ways to do the same thing is never a good idea, because it increases your odds of failure by 100%. So choose one way and stick to it. A year from now some junior dev will blow something up because he gets confused by the alternatives.)

Comment: looks good but why not simply keep the registration but use the [autofac abstraction](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/) for it?

Comment: @JoelHarkes That's what we have now. But we decided it's better not to do things in two separate ways - it reduces maintanability, reduces readability, and increases confusion. We adopted Autofac, so we need to be all in.

Comment: the whole point of the abstraction is so that you don't need to be all in. If you wanted to switch containers, you wouldn't have to rewrite all your startup code.

Comment: @EricB When will we ever switch containers? We learned the hard way not to get obsessed with creating abstractions over abstractions over abstractions. The product will not survive that long. If it lasts for two years it will be a dinosaur. The "switching out" idea is always a waste of time.

Comment: It's **3 lines of code** you need to add, to reuse your Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection registrations. And the abstractions are already there, you don't need to write your own abstractions for it. `IServiceCollection` can be reused by other IoC container with little work. `IServiceProvider` would act as a thin wrapper around the containers resolve method

Comment: @Tseng, I know that but it doesn't answer the question. And a whole team of experience devs decided to do things differently. We are migrating, we need to know the path. And we have other subsystems which don't reference ASP.

Comment: @grokky I have been looking for the same thing as you, and I came across this blog post on the MSDN forums: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/01/26/comparing-asp-net-core-ioc-service-life-times-and-autofac-ioc-instance-scopes/ It has "migration guide" similar to yours, though a bit simpler.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `.AddXxx` methods from `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` to register it and pass the `IServiceCollection` to autofac.

This makes it easier to change between containers.

Of course, if you need certain features of Autofac/3rd party IoC container (autodiscovery etc), then you need to use the containers native methods.

```
private readonly IContainer container;
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
    // your normal registrations
    services.AddSingleton<IMySingleton,MySingleton>();

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.Populate(services);

    // build container 
    container = builder.Build();

    // and return it
    return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
}
```

Comment: This is what we have now. But I want to confirm the migration table above, from someone with experience in both containers.