# Keeping .NET Dependency Injection in Order

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

Recently I started working on a new project using .NET Core 2.1 and I decided to use the SOLID principles and create a nice project structure.

It is a Web API project. Everything is working fine I use a lot dependency injection, most of the stuff is easy to test.

And that's the part where I have to register all my services. I am literally having hundreds of lines looking like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<...>();
```

or

```
services.AddScoped<...>();
```

I have one line for every service and for a small project it would be fine. However when I have hundreds of these it becomes on BIG mess. Basically the whole project is in a super nice order and there comes the Startup.cs that is full of services.AddX statements.

I was think of creating static classes with methods that register the services but that just doesn't look fine.

I will need to add more services in future and I can't just keep creating static classes or filling the old ones because I will end up with the same mess again and it will be more difficult for me to remember where am I registering a given service.

Comment: I’m very much interested why you have *hundreds* of them. That seems like a gigantic project, or a problem in design.

Comment: Did you overdo it with DI perhaps, and registered things that don't need injecting? If you really need hundreds of services you probably need to break the single Web API project into multiple independent projects.

Comment: It really is a big project, that API I am talking about is sending and receiving different requests from other applications. Every event has its own consumer that is registered as a service. A consumer is a class that holds methods that are executed when a request is received. And as different things happen when different requests are received I have a lot of different consumers => many services.

Comment: Assuming you *do* need them and can't break the project apart, you can use reflection to find the classes to register based on their names, attributes or interfaces they implement. That's how more advanced IoC containers like [Autofac](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/scanning.html) work. You can [integrate Autofac with ASP.NET Core](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html) or you can implement a similar technique

Comment: You can have each group of services (assemly) export its own RegisterServices method. For fancy cosmetics, make it an `AddMyStuff()` extension method in the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` namespace. See `AddMvc()` for an example.

Comment: That's probably the simplest and the most elegant way. But I am now concerned if it should still keep using the MS DI Container. Is it okay to have so many services registered?

Comment: Hundreds is not a lot. Not for the DI container at least.

Comment: _However when I have hundreds of these it becomes on BIG mess_ - It shouldn't be a mess, because you will have one function where you execute hundreds of simple, clear and understandable lines of code.

Comment: @Fabio - "hundreds of simple, clear and understandable lines" is a bit of an oxymoron. It needs to be broken up.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have hundreds of them, you may want to replace the default container with for example Autofac. These type of frameworks supports modules or kind of "subcontainers".

> A module is a small class that can be used to bundle up a set of related components behind a ‘facade’ to simplify configuration and deployment.

[Replace DI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1)
[Autofac modules](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/modules.html)

Comment: Do you have any idea if the process of migrating to Autofac can happen easily or I should have started using it from the begging?

Comment: Maybe take a look at this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809618/migration-from-asp-net-cores-container-to-autofac
  I used autofac in wcf projects, but in .net core I haven´t had problems with the default container.

Answer (score 1):

You can have each logical group of services (assemly) export its own RegisterServices method. It is the responsibility of that assembly to select lifetime and scope anyway.

For cosmetics, make it an `AddMyStuff()` extension method in the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` namespace.

See `AddMvc()` for an example. Look it up (<kbd>F12</kbd>) and notice the difference between the assembly and the namespace it is in.